# how to query in php when using select query having single and double quotes

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

```
$pdo = $db->getConnection();  

 $query="""select column_name as "3-D" from table where colume_code='Goa'"""
          
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Error executing query";
        exit;
    }
```

while executing the query in php i'm getting error in executing query
its need to return 3-D with values

Comment: $query="select column_name as \"3-D\" from table where colume_code='Goa'"

Comment: Using [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string syntax would be clean and safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query="select column_name as \"3-D\" from table where colume_code='Goa'";
```